# Multiselect UI Component "prepared-for-send" being added as custom attribute

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent

Using one-page-checkout I want to add a field to the top of the form - Delivery Day, where the customer can choose their preferred day of delivery, as a multi-select showing the options Monday to Friday. I've added the custom attribute using an `extension_attributes.xml` file. To include the form field I'm using the below xml in my layout:

```
<item name="delivery_days" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/multiselect</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <!--customScope is used to group elements within a single form (e.g. they can be validated separately)-->
        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_attributes</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/multiselect</item>
    </item>
    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">shippingAddress.custom_attributes.delivery_days</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delivery Days?</item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    </item>
    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="monday" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Monday</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">monday</item>
        </item>
        <item name="tuesday" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Tuesday</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">tuesday</item>
        </item>
        <item name="wednesday" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Wednesday</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">wednesday</item>
        </item>
        <item name="thursday" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Thursday</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">thursday</item>
        </item>
        <item name="friday" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Friday</item>
            <item name="value" xsi:type="string">friday</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

The form element is added and shows the options.

The issue I'm having is that when I try to submit I get the following message:

> Property "DeliveryDays-perpared-for-send" does not have accessor method "getDeliveryDays-prepared-for-send" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface".

I've found that the ui component `magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\form\element\multiselect.js` is adding this to the data that is being sent:

```
/**
 * Sets the prepared data to dataSource
 * by path, where key is component link to dataSource with
 * suffix "-prepared-for-send"
 *
 * @param {Array} data - current component value
 */
setPrepareToSendData: function (data) {
    if (_.isUndefined(data) || !data.length) {
        data = '';
    }

    this.source.set(this.dataScope + '-prepared-for-send', data);
},
```

#### Why is M2 Multiselect UI Component adding a new field to be sent to the server?

#### What do I need to change to make M2 not show the error message AND save the submitted values?